# Magento 1.x js and css path mismatch after migration

Tags: javascript, css, magento

correct the value for web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url
set the value to 0 for both dev/js/merge_files and dev/css/merge_css_files

Here is my path

http://example.com/frontend/base/default/css/tinybox/style.css 
 http://example.com/frontend/rwd/butysite/css/styles.css

http://example.com/scriptaculous/effects.js

But i need url  like below

http://example.com/skin/frontend/base/default/css/tinybox/style.css